# Extract context URL of a substring

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am building a scrapy app where I need to extract the full URL if a substring in that URL matches.

**For example:**

Let's assume a page has the following URLs of my interest:

- `/public/flag?cat=Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books&url=http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,,0130260363,00%2Ben-USS_01DBC.html`
- `/public/flag?cat=Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books&url=http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus7/html/book.html`
- `/public/flag?cat=Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books&url=http://www.diveintopython.net/`
- `/public/flag?cat=Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books&url=http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2011/foundations-of-python-network-programming/`
- [18 more]

But my search string is `flag?cat=Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books`

Which returns only the matched part of the URLs and *not the full URLs*. How do I get the full URLs as listed above?

Here's a simple scrapy test case based on the example:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        #scrapy.shell.inspect_response( response, self )
        results = response.xpath('//body').re('(flag\?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks)')
        print results
```

**Output:**

```
[
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks',
    u'flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks'
]
```

*Expected Output:*

```
[
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pearsonhighered.com%2Feducator%2Facademic%2Fproduct%2F0%2C%2C0130260363%2C00%252Ben-USS_01DBC.html"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brpreiss.com%2Fbooks%2Fopus7%2Fhtml%2Fbook.html"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.diveintopython.net%2F"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Frhodesmill.org%2Fbrandon%2F2011%2Ffoundations-of-python-network-programming%2F"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.techbooksforfree.com%2Fperlpython.shtml"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.freetechbooks.com%2Fpython-f6.html"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fgreenteapress.com%2Fthinkpython%2F"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.network-theory.co.uk%2Fpython%2Fintro%2F"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.freenetpages.co.uk%2Fhp%2Falan.gauld%2F"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wiley.com%2FWileyCDA%2FWileyTitle%2FproductCd-0471219754.html"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fhetland.org%2Fwriting%2Fpractical-python%2F"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fsysadminpy.com%2F"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.qtrac.eu%2Fpy3book.html"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wiley.com%2FWileyCDA%2FWileyTitle%2FproductCd-0764548077.html"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.packtpub.com%2Fpython-3-object-oriented-programming%2Fbook"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.network-theory.co.uk%2Fpython%2Flanguage%2F"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pearsonhighered.com%2Feducator%2Facademic%2Fproduct%2F0%2C%2C0130409561%2C00%252Ben-USS_01DBC.html"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.informit.com%2Fstore%2Fproduct.aspx%3Fisbn%3D0201616165%26redir%3D1"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pearsonhighered.com%2Feducator%2Facademic%2Fproduct%2F0%2C%2C0201748843%2C00%252Ben-USS_01DBC.html"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.informit.com%2Fstore%2Fproduct.aspx%3Fisbn%3D0672317354"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fgnosis.cx%2FTPiP%2F"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.informit.com%2Fstore%2Fproduct.aspx%3Fisbn%3D0130211192"><img src="/img/flag.png" alt="[!]" title="report an issue with this listing'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the *`.re()` would return you only the part that matched the expression*. Instead, if you want to continue using the regular expression check, use the [`re:test()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions) hook:

```
response.xpath('//body//a/@href[re:test(., "flag\?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks")]').extract()
```

Produces the following on my end:

```
[
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pearsonhighered.com%2Feducator%2Facademic%2Fproduct%2F0%2C%2C0130260363%2C00%252Ben-USS_01DBC.html', 
    u'/public/flag?cat=Computers%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2FPython%2FBooks&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brpreiss.com%2Fbooks%2Fopus7%2Fhtml%2Fbook.html',
    ...
]
```